# is it possible to use ?? operator on class member?

Tags: c#, .net

In c# there is a great operator '??' that makes life much simplier. Instead of writing `(foo != null)? foo : default` I can write `foo ?? default`. Is there a simple way to apply this operator to class memeber e.g. in situation `(foo != null)? foo.bar : default`?

**upd:** OK I'll expalin a bit:

```
string a = (someVeryLongVariableName != null)? someVeryLongVariableName : ""; // Long way
string a = someVeryLongVariableName ?? ""; // Shorter with same result
string a = (someVeryLongVariableName != null)? someVeryLongVariableName.bar : ""; // What's the shorter way in this case?
```

**upd2:** Situation when I need this feature looks like this:

```
if (foo is MyClass) bar1 = (foo as MyClass).SpecificMember;
if (foo is OneMoreClass) bar2 = (foo as OneMoreClass).AnotherSpecificMember;
if (foo is MyFavoriteClass) bar3 = (foo as MyFavoriteClass).YetAnotherMember;
```

It'll be cool if I can shorten these to something like

```
bar1 = (foo as MyClass).SpecificMember ?? null;
```

Maybe it's not much shorter but it casts foo to MyClass only once and explicitly initializes bar with default value.  And most important it looks nicer.

Comment: what's not simple writing (foo != null) ? foo.bar : default ??

Comment: What? I'm not sure you can get much simpler...am I missing something?

Comment: in the upd2 you are assigning 3 different variables (bar1, bar2 and bar3). I cannot see a way how shortening that to bar1 assignment alone will help you. Or did you intend to assign only bar1 and by mistake gave a wrong example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deep Null checking, is there a better way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in C# operator that does what you describe. A new operator (most people suggest `.?` or `?.`) has been [requested](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/192177/a-bit-more-c-syntactic-sugar-for-nulls), but it has [not been added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way/2081709#2081709) to C#.

As a workaround, many developers implement an `IfNotNull` extension method, e.g., in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123088/possible-pitfalls-of-using-this-extension-method-based-shorthand) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way/2081942#2081942).

Answer (score 3):

Only if you have some way of doing it like this

```
  (foo ?? defaultFoo).bar
```

But that would mean that you'd have to have an object of the same time as foo around with its bar set up the way you want it.

Comment: and what if `foo` is an expression like `(foo as string).Length`?

Comment: @Poma, what do you mean foo is an expression?  In this case an expression is exactly what you are using foo as.  However, your case would not work because .Length is an int which cannot be null.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's currently no such operator (access member or return default value) in C#. You can, of course, write a method to do this:

```
public static TMember MemberOrDefault<T, TMember>(T obj, 
                                                  Func<T, TMember> accessor, 
                                                  TMember @default) {
    return obj == null ? @default : accessor(obj);
}

string a = MemberOrDefault(someVeryLongVariableName, v => v.bar, "");
```

Note, however, that this will still return null if `someVeryLongVariableName.bar` is null (which might or might not be what you want).