# Converting a null type to a list (error handling)

Tags: c#, null, argumentnullexception

So, the title is a bit misleading and I'll sort it out first.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
public static ADescription CreateDescription(string file, string name, params string[] othername)
{
    return new ADescription(file, name, othername.ToList<string>());
}
```

This will throw a `System.ArgumentNullException` in a case where the user deliberately enters a null at the end. For e.g.:

```
ADescription.CreateDescription("file", "name", null); // example
```

Now I have a property that basically gets & sets the `othername` list. My concern is that I will have to check at every stage like (in the property, as well as in this method):

```
if (othername == null){
   // do nothing
}
else{
    othername.ToList<string>; // for example
}
```

because, null is acceptable for `othername`. Is there any way that c# natively provides this capability where if `othername` is null, then it wouldn't really operate ToList() on that.

Comment: Your second call to `ADescription.CreateDescription` will not throw on the `ToList` call.

Comment: In the property setter, if you initialise new empty `List<string>` when it is null, will that solve your problem?

Comment: That would actually be a wrong thing to do. A List<string> would make that non-null.

Comment: why not a simple ternary operator? return new ADescription(file, name, othername==null?null:othername.ToList<string>());

Comment: That sounds good and affectively that's what I intend to do. But I am wondering if there's a better programming practice in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
 return new ADescription(file, name, othername==null?null:othername.ToList<string>());
```

Or create an extension method as described in the accepted response here [Possible pitfalls of using this (extension method based) shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123088/possible-pitfalls-of-using-this-extension-method-based-shorthand):

```
public static class IfNotNullExtensionMethod
{
    public static U IfNotNull<T, U>(this T t, Func<T, U> fn)
    {
        return t != null ? fn(t) : default(U);
    }
}
```

Your code would be:

```
return new ADescription(file, name, othername.IfNotNull(on => on.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an extension method to handle this:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<T> ToListIfNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return (enumerable != null ? new List<T>(enumerable) : null);
    }
}
```

Then you can substitute the extension method wherever you would otherwise use `ToList()`.

```
return new ADescription(file, name, othername.ToListIfNotNull());
```