# Invoking a predicate throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, null, predicate

I have different properties that can provide a value and I would like to return the first one that satisfies a specified condition.

The problem is when one of the sources is a `class` and is `null`, I do get a nice *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*.

I can't find a property to check against the nullity of the current provider, whether on the `Func<T,bool>` or the `Expression<Func<Media,T>>`.

Do you know how can I check against the nullity of a function target ?

```
public int TempoInteger
{
    get
    {
        double result;
        // In this case, AudioSummary is a class that can be null
        if (TryGetValue(out result, s => s > 0.0d, s => s.TempoBass, s => s.AudioSummary.Tempo))
        {
            return (int)Math.Round(result);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

private AudioSummary AudioSummary {get; set;}

/// <summary>
/// Tries to get a value from multiple expressions, first expression value that satisfies the predicate will be returned. If no value satisifes the predicate the default value of <typeparamref name="T"/> will be returned.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="result"></param>
/// <param name="predicate"></param>
/// <param name="expressions"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool TryGetValue<T>(out T result, Func<T, bool> predicate, params Expression<Func<Media, T>>[] expressions)
{
    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        Func<Media, T> func = expression.Compile();

        // 'System.NullReferenceException' occurs here when AudioSummary is null
        T t = func(this);

        var b = predicate(t);
        if (b)
        {
            result = t;
            return true;
        }
    }
    result = default(T);
    return false;
}

public sealed class AudioSummary
{

    [JsonProperty("tempo")]
    public double Tempo { get; set; }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I don't see `AudioSummary` in the code, except for comments..

Comment: I've added the property to the code and a trimmed definition of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several workaround for what you're trying to achieve.

1. Wrap the expression invocation inside a try-catch block

   ```
   private bool TryGetValue<T>(
     out T result, 
     Func<T, bool> predicate, 
     params Expression<Func<Media, T>>[] expressions) 
   {
     ...
     T t;
     try
     {
       t = func(this);
     }
     catch (NullReferenceException)
     {
       t = default(T);
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Validate the expression for `Null` before passing it to `TryGetValue()`

   ```
   public int TempoInteger {
     get {
       double result;

       if (TryGetValue(out result, 
         s => s > 0.0d, 
         s => s.TempoBass, 
         s => s.AudioSummary != null ? s.AudioSummary.Tempo : 0.0d)) 
       {
         return (int)Math.Round(result);
       }

       return -1;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use the `IfNotNull` extension method, which does the same thing as point `#2` but *fancier*

   ```
   public static class IfNotNullExtensionMethod
   {
     public static T2 IfNotNull<T1, T2>(this T1 t, Func<T1, T2> fn)
       where T1: class
     {
       return t != null ? fn(t) : default(T2);
     }
   }

   ...
   public int TempoInteger {
     get {
       double result;

       if (TryGetValue(out result, 
         s => s > 0.0d, 
         s => s.TempoBass, 
         s => s.AudioSummary.IfNotNull(x => x.Tempo))) 
       {
         return (int)Math.Round(result);
       }

       return -1;
     }
   }
   ...
   ```

   ***Credits*** for the `IfNotNull` extension methods goes to: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854591/how-to-check-for-nulls-in-a-deep-lambda-expression), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123088/possible-pitfalls-of-using-this-extension-method-based-shorthand), and [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/01/nullpropagating_extension_meth.html)
4. Use the `Maybe` extensions method: [maybe.codeplex.com](http://maybe.codeplex.com/). *(disclaimer: I haven't tested this one, but it's mentioned in point `#3` credits links)*

Answer (score 1):

Before invoking `TryGetValue()` check for null objects `s` and `AudioSummary` because if `AudioSummary` is null you can't get to property `AudioSummary.Tempo`.