# null-coalescing operator evaluation?

Tags: c#, .net, operators

```
object bread(food foo)
{
    return foo.ingredient ?? "cheese";
}
```

If foo exits, but ingredient is `null`, I get `"cheese"`.
My question, including an assumption:
If foo itself is `null` will `"chesse"` be returned or will it throw an `ArgutmentNullException`?

My GUESS is that the NullCoalescingOperator is implemented more or less like this:

```
object nco(object lhs, object rhs)
{
    if(lhs != null)
        return lhs;
    else
        return rhs;
}
```

Therefore **passing** `foo.ingredient` already causes the exception(since you cannot check a field in an object that you don't have) and thus it is thrown.
Would make sense.

Is this idea correct / how is the nco implemented and why?

Comment: Do you mean `??` or `?`? What C# version? I have read about a syntax like `foo?.ingredient` but am not sure this made it into C# yet.

Comment: If `foo` is null, you will get `NullReferenceException`

Comment: You can assert your own assumption by trying your bread example in a simple test project. What is the reason you didn't do that?

Comment: @MarkO quite practically the reason is, that I'm currently on the train, when I started to wonder about this.

Comment: Note that in [some versions of C#](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation) it will be allowed to use `return foo?.ingredient ?? "cheese";` where the operator `?.` is a new one in C#. See my link.

Comment: @Jeppe thanks, "null propagation" is the term I couldn't think of. See for example this (badly-titled) question: [Possible pitfalls of using this (extension method based) shorthand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123088/possible-pitfalls-of-using-this-extension-method-based-shorthand).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen cutting edge knowledge right there. That'll be an interesting option in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get a `NullReferenceException` if foo is null.

So you've got to treat this case, with a ternary (if else) rather than a coalesce.

```
return (foo == null || foo.ingredient == null) 
           ? "cheese" 
           : foo.ingredient;
```

Comment: Answer plus a way to achive the intended and I didn't even ask for that, Sweet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you idea is absolutely correct because:

```
foo.ingredient ?? "cheese";
```

Equals to:

```
foo.ingredient != null ? foo.ingredient : "cheese";
```

What you might like, in VS2014 CTP they already have new operator `?.`, which will do what you need:

```
foo?.ingredient ?? "cheese";
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it'll throw an exception. You cannot access a property of the object, that's not there. If you want secure yourself from an error, you could write:

```
return (foo == null) ? "cheese" : (foo.ingredient ?? "cheese");
```

Comment: I can see Raphaël Althaus's answer is even cleaner.